# There's no ProtonVPN-Cli installation package on 20.04.05 Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: vpn

I upgraded from Ubuntu Linux 18.04 to 20.04 last year.
There was a package I used on Ubuntu 18.04 known as protonvpn-cli
which allowed me to change access to UDP from TCP and vice-versa via a Terminal command line.
I have a ProtonVPN account and a Protonmail account, both of which work via Firefox Browser.
I used to be able to run the command in terminal as proton-cli UDP or TCP.
Now using 20.04, that is not available, or there is an alternative that I'm unaware of.
Other than the fact that Proton VPN may have chosen not to provide a protonvpn-cli install package, does anyone know whether 20.04 doesn't need to use protonvpn-cli to switch UDP to TCP?
Thank you.
Shobuz99

Comment: If your details are correct (ie. you're still using 20.04.5) then I'll suggest you apply all security fixes asap.. as a fully upgraded 20.04 system has reported itself as 20.04.6 for awhile now (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ but note that represents the ISO release date with installed systems reporting as 20.04.6 the week before that date!)

Comment: I made an error. My version IS 20.04.6. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does not provide protonvpn packages. It never has.

For protonvpn packages, consult Proton VPN support: https://protonvpn.com/support/